# Logic of following Fork

Tags: c, fork

I am new to C and I found this code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define DISPLAY \
"mypid[%3.3d] - ppid[%3.3d] - f1[%3.3d] - f2[%3.3d] -  f3[%3.3d]\n"
main(void) {
   int f1, f2, f3, mypid, ppid;
   f1 = (int) fork();
   sleep(1);
   f2 = (int) fork();
   sleep(2);
   f3 = (int) fork();
   sleep(3);
   mypid=(int) getpid();
   ppid=(int) getppid();
   printf(DISPLAY, mypid, ppid, f1, f2, f3);
   waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
   waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
   waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
   exit (0);
}
```

Anyone could help me, what is actually the logic behind this code? I've trying to run it several time, but I still have no idea.

Result of this code:

> mypid[9341] - ppid[9339] - f1[000] - f2[9342] -  f3[9344]
>
> mypid[9346] - ppid[9342] - f1[000] - f2[000] -  f3[000]
>
> mypid[9339] - ppid[9220] - f1[9341] - f2[9343] -  f3[9345]
>
> mypid[9342] - ppid[9341] - f1[000] - f2[000] -  f3[9346]
>
> mypid[9344] - ppid[9341] - f1[000] - f2[9342] -  f3[000]
>
> mypid[9343] - ppid[9339] - f1[9341] - f2[000] -  f3[9347]
>
> mypid[9347] - ppid[9343] - f1[9341] - f2[000] -  f3[000]
>
> mypid[9345] - ppid[9339] - f1[9341] - f2[9343] -  f3[000]

Comment: I love how you **wrongly** cast to `int` in 5 places instead of changing `int` to `pid_t` in one place.

Comment: Which part of this, specifically, are you having trouble with?

Comment: Why do you think there is some logic here, or that the author had any idea of, well, anything?

Comment: i've edited my question by adding the result. I just want to know why the result is like that.

Comment: Why are you surprised by the result? Did you expect something different?

Comment: If you are surprised by the order of output, that is arbitrary, depends on the scheduling policy of the OS ...

Comment: @DanielFischer, if the root pid has been defined and we know f1, f2, and f3, it is impossible to define or may be guess the "mypid"?

Comment: You can read the pids of the direct children of the original from its `f1, f2, f3`. You can't determine the pids of the grandchildren etc. from the original process's data.

Comment: Could you explain about how to do it?

Comment: @cnicutar: Not that simple. Printing `pid_t` would need a cast too...

Comment: @R.. That's true. Still, a cast when printing is probably preferable I think.

Comment: Probably. Or just be lazy and use `intmax_t`...

Answer (score 1):

The `(int)` casts are useless since `pid_t` is compatible with `int`; the main advantage to store the pids as `int` is that you can print them without cast.

Your code shows a very bad usage of `fork();` never use it like this!

The correct use is :

```
f1 = fork();
if (f1 < 0) { perror ("fork"); exit (1); }

if (f1 == 0) {  
    /* here code of child 1 */
    exit (0);
}

f2 = fork();
if (f2 < 0) { perror ("fork"); exit (1); }

if (f2 == 0) {  
    /* here code of child 2 */
    exit (0);
}

/* same for child 3 */

/* Now wait for each child */
wait (NULL);
wait (NULL);
wait (NULL);
```

To respond to your question: `fork`1 creates 1 process, then `fork`2 creates 2 processes
(it is called by the parent and the child) and `fork`3 creates 4, so you have 8 processes.

The print order is scheduler dependent; run it several times and order will change (but not so much because of the `sleep`s; suppress them to see more changes, and to see `ppid == 1` when the parent is already terminated).

The `wait` are wrong placed, since the children don't have to (here they will fail). `waitpid(-1,NULL,0)` is equivalent to `wait(NULL)`.

Comment: also one more question, as daniel said above, we can read the pid from the f1, f2, and f3. Do you know how to do it? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "read the pid"? f1, f2 and f3 doesn't represent a process, their value depends on the process.

Answer (score 0):

Here the program

- forked thrice & stored the respective results in f1, f2 & f3.
- then gets current pid & parent's pid.
- Prints all of it.

And, regarding fork:

- If fork() returns a negative value, the creation of a child process was unsuccessful.
- If fork() returns a zero to the newly created child process.
- If fork() returns a positive value, the process ID of the child process, to the parent.

---

**EDIT**

The output looks like the above, because your format specifier is

```
"mypid[%3.3d] - ppid[%3.3d] - f1[%3.3d] - f2[%3.3d] -  f3[%3.3d]\n"
```

interpreted as:

```
mypid[<first argument>] - ppid[<second argument>] ...
```

leading to

```
mypid[9341] - ppid[9339] ...
```

Comment: I've edited my question and adding the result. Could you explain why the result is like that? I am really new to C. Thank you so much.

Comment: on the top you have defined the format specifier using #define DISPLAY... see updates.

Comment: Not the format i mean, but the order of the process, especially for the f1, f2, and f3.

Comment: Just as Daniel commented, it is arbitrary.

Comment: so, if the root pid has been defined and we know f1, f2, and f3, it is impossible to define or may be guess the "mypid"?